# Gradle download timeout/retry

Tags: gradle, ivy

I am on a flaky network (or there is some kind of proxy or virus checker in the way) so my gradle dependencies downloads (external module dependencies mavenCentral()) hangs sometimes.

A local repo would help, but are there any settings for timeouts and retries?

The download starts, and then it hangs, and times out after the default socket timeout,

I can emulate this with wget

> wget -d
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/santuario/xmlsec/1.5.2/xmlsec-1.5.2-sources.jar
>   DEBUG output created by Wget 1.11.4 on Windows-MSVC.
>
> --2013-01-23 13:52:01--  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/santuario/xmls
>   ec/1.5.2/xmlsec-1.5.2-sources.jar Resolving repo1.maven.org... seconds
>   0.00, 68.232.34.223 Caching repo1.maven.org => 68.232.34.223 Connecting to repo1.maven.org|68.232.34.223|:80... seconds 0.00,
>   connected. Created socket 352. Releasing 0x003311d0 (new refcount 1).
>
> ---request begin--- GET /maven2/org/apache/santuario/xmlsec/1.5.2/xmlsec-1.5.2-sources.jar
>   HTTP/1.0 User-Agent: Wget/1.11.4 Accept: */* Host: repo1.maven.org
>   Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> ---request end--- HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
>   ---response begin--- HTTP/1.0 200 OK Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Type: application/java-archive Date: Wed, 23 Jan 2013 12:52:01
>   GMT Last-Modified: Mon, 14 May 2012 08:47:03 GMT Server: ECAcc
>   (lhr/4ABA) X-Cache: HIT Content-Length: 577534 Connection: keep-alive
>
> ---response end--- 200 OK Registered socket 352 for persistent reuse. Length: 577534 (564K) [application/java-archive] Saving to:
>   `xmlsec-1.5.2-sources.jar.1'
>
> 5% [=>                                     ] 33,328      --.-K/s  eta
>   17m 52s ^

I would like it to timeout faster and retry the download,

Comment: Can you add more details? I'm not sure what you're looking for here, I'm sure others will feel the same way.

Comment: Sounds like you really need local repository. Won't completely solve your problems (artifacts still need to be downloaded) but would certainly help stabilise existing builds by caching files.

Comment: Gradle just takes ages. :(